# How to open a modal on an element when the page loads?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to call the specific link id `#ext` when page loads instead of clicking it manually to show the modal popup. However I am not able to achieve it. Can someone look into code and suggest a change?

```
<!-- Modal HTML embedded directly into document -->
<div id="ex1" class="modal">
<a href="https://www.siteallow.com"><img src="image.jpg" /></a>
</div>

<!-- Link to open the modal -->
<p><a href="#ex1" rel="modal:open" onload="loadImage()">Open Modal</a></p>
```

The above code works fine when I do click on the link on the page "Open Modal". I want it to be called when page is loaded to show popup auto.

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dypu9tLj/1/)

Just for reference I am using this to show a modal popup: https://jquerymodal.com/

Answer (score 4):

From the [documentation](https://github.com/kylefox/jquery-modal#opening):

> You can manually open a modal by calling the .modal() method on the element:

As such you just need to call the `modal()` method on `$('#ex1')` when the page loads:

```
jQuery(function($) {
  $('#ex1').modal();
});
```

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $('#ex1').modal();
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-modal/0.9.1/jquery.modal.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-modal/0.9.1/jquery.modal.min.css">
<div id="ex1" class="modal">
  <a href="https://www.example.com"><img src="image.png" /></a>
</div>
<p>
  <a href="#ex1" rel="modal:open" onload="loadImage()">Open Modal</a>
</p>
```

Comment: @SyedRazaAli if this answer solved your problem, please mark it as solved.